# MySQL running out of memory after multiple queries

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to iterate through two tables and pull records.  The tables have hundreds of thousands of rows, so I know pulling them all at once is not going to work, so looping through and pulling them in batches seems like the best approach, but it's not releasing the memory, so after a few pulls it runs out of memory and crashes.

**My Output**

```
    400000 Pulled, currently on 0 || Out of 1623230
    400000 Pulled, currently on 400000 || Out of 1623230

    Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 39 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\misc\manage tickets\test2.php on line 38
```

Ignore the line number, I have a giant block of commented out code at the top of the file.

The code is:

```
$iterate = 400000;


$query = "SELECT id FROM $old_db.ticketaudit_archive";
$get = $g_mysqli->query($query);
$count = $get->num_rows;

$i = 0;
while($i <= $count){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM $old_db.ticketaudit_archive LIMIT $i, $iterate";
    $get = $g_mysqli->query($query);
    echo $get->num_rows.' Pulled, currently on '.$i.' || Out of '.$count.'<br>';
    while($z = $get->fetch_assoc()){
        $old_ticket_id = $z[old_ticket_id];
        $ticket_id = $z[ticket_id];
        unset($z[old_ticket_id], $z[ticket_id], $z[id]);
        if($old_ticket_id != ''){
            $ticketaudit[old_ticket_id][$old_ticket_id][] = $z;
            $xx += 1;
        }
        elseif($ticket_id != ''){
            $ticketaudit[ticket_id][$ticket_id][] = $z;
            $xx += 1;
        }
    }
    $i += $iterate;
    $get->free();
    $get->free_result();
    $get->close();
}
```

I've been at this all day, and can't find a way to get MySQL to drop the damned memory cache for previous queries.

Comment: It's not MySQL running out of memory, it's PHP. That's an important difference.

Comment: You're pulling data from 400,000 rows, if it's a lot of data then you're likely going to run into memory problems.

Comment: $i and number of rows may not increment perfectly, if you have deleted rows, your numbers will not match up. You should probably be using "foreach" instead of by an incrementing scheme.

Comment: I've tried it with 100,000 rows, but it seems to always break after the same amount of data gets pulled.  The table has 1.6 million rows that I need to pull out, organize, and merge with another table.

I'm also certain it's MySQL and not PHP, since I've tried changing the PHP file size limitations and it hasn't had any impact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may be looking for unbuffered queries:

> Unbuffered MySQL queries execute the query and then return a resource while the data is still waiting on the MySQL server for being fetched. This uses less memory on the PHP-side, but can increase the load on the server. Unless the full result set was fetched from the server no further queries can be sent over the same connection. Unbuffered queries can also be referred to as "use result".

Here's an unbuffered query example:

`$get = $g_mysqli->query($query, MYSQLI_USE_RESULT);`

You can read more [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.buffering.php)

Comment: Awesome, glad it helped! You may want to accept the answer :)